# How to store 2 types of CGPath definitions in an array in Swift

Tags: swift, types, enums

I want an array to store the data required to generate both quad and cubic curves. In order to do this, I have done the following:

1. Defined a CubicCurve struct with properties start, end, cp1 & cp2
2. Defined a QuadCurve struct with properties start, end and cp
3. Defined an enum called Path with a case of cubicCurve with a CubicCurve associated value and a case of quadCurve with a QuadCurve associated value.
4. Defined an array of type Path `[Path]()`

I define a CubicCurve but cannot add it to the array, as the array is of type Path:

```
struct CubicCurve {
    var start : CGPoint
    var end : CGPoint
    var cp1 : CGPoint
    var cp2 : CGPoint
}

struct QuadCurve {
    var start : CGPoint
    var end : CGPoint
    var cp : CGPoint
}

enum Path {
    case cubicCurve(CubicCurve)
    case quadCurve(QuadCurve)
}

let paths = [Path]()

let start = CGPoint(100,100)
let end = CGPoint(500,500)
let cp1 = CGPoint(250,200)
let cp2 = CGPoint(150,300)

let curve = CubicCurve(start: start, end: end, cp1: cp1, cp2: cp2)

paths.append(curve)  // Doesn't work - path is of type Path, not CubicCurve
```

How do I actually get my values into my array?

I have no formal CS training (OK - 'A" level CS from years ago) and am a bit hazy on the more advanced use of Swift's Classes vs. structs vs. enums, so I might be going about this completely wrong. I think that what I am doing is better than using [AnyObject] or [Any].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
paths.append(.cubicCurve(curve))
```

Because 'curve' is an instance of a CubicCurve type but 'Path.cubicCurve(curve)' is an instance of a Path.

Answer (score 1):

`CubicPath` and `Path` are not compatible types.

To properly add a new item to a `[Path]`, you need a `Path` value. Well, there are only two `case`s in `Path`, so it can only be one of them - `.cubicCurve` or `.quadCurve`

Obviously what you want is a `. cubicCurve`. We also need to put an associated value in it. You've already created a `CubicPath` instance, right? Use that! So here's the value that we are putting into the array

```
let path = .cubicCurve(curve)
```

Now we can add it in

```
paths.append(path)
```